# Uploading data with double quotes within content in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, double-quotes, uploading

Trying this since last 3 hours. I am trying to upload the which actually looks like this

```
5635424,Utah,,ST GEORGE CITY,,,,84770,,,,,South,,,PLANTATIONS,Drive,,,,1157,,,"WORLDMARK, THE CLUB AT ST GEORGE",,,UNIT,,,,-113.62304518432343,37.089219399452638,12STG6686207989,{29D86F48-5D11-4CFE-B161-7B6D0C0190E3},,,Utah AGRC,WASHINGTON COUNTY,ST GEORGE,20170817000000,,
```

It actually contains the double quotes ("") within some fields and the data is comma seperated.

I am trying to upload that data and every time I got this error.

The query I am using

```
COPY "nad_data" FROM 'D:\AddressEvaluation\NAD.csv' DELIMITER ','
quote E'\b' CSV encoding 'win-1252';
```

The error I am facing.

```
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY nad_data, line 13577: "5621646,Utah,,ST GEORGE 
 CITY,,,,84770,,,,,South,,,PLANTATIONS,Drive,,,,1157,,,"WORLDMARK, THE CLUB 
 A..."
  ********** Error **********
```

Is there anything wrong, or Am I missing something? 
Please help.

Comment: `line 13577` ... this seems to imply that the first 13576 lines went according to plan.  Can you insect this line and check for, as the error message implies, that there is extra data after the last expected column?

Comment: No, This line perfectly fits under the columns but the double quotes are actually making the mess. I have mention that line in the question. I might be wrong but this is what I came up with, sir.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the line that fails, the quote character of your data is the double-quote, which is also the default in the [CSV format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180).

So try to remove this from the COPY invocation:

```
quote E'\b'
```

`\b` corresponds to backslash and in that context it just seems wrong.